# Empty controller blocks view. Why?

Tags: ember.js

I have been experimenting with using Ember with a JSON server but without without ember-data. My test app renders a directory of images from a small JSON structure (generated from a little Go server).

Can anyone explain to me why, if I uncomment the App.FileController in the code below, the corresponding File view fails to render?

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('files',function(){
    this.resource('file',{path:':file_id'});
  });
});

App.FilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.File.findAll();
  }
});

App.FileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, args) {
        controller.set('model', App.File.find(args.id));
    },
    model: function(args) {
        return App.File.find(args.file_id);
    }
});

App.File = Ember.Object.extend({
    urlPath: function(){
      return "/pics/" + this.get('id');
    }.property('id'),   
});
```

If I uncomment this, things break:

```
// App.FileController = Ember.Controller.extend({

// });
```

(namely, the  File sub-view no longer renders at all.)

```
App.File.reopenClass({
    find: function(id){
        file = App.File.create({'id':id});
        return file;
    },

    findAll: function() {
        return $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/").then(
            function(response) {
                var files = [];
                response.Files.forEach(function (filename) {
                    files.push(App.File.create({'id':filename}));
                });
                return files;
            }
        );
    },

});
```

Also, is there something fundamental that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: i'm not sure if that's a mistake, but normally, i'd have `FileController` extend `ObjectController` and add `content: null` in there (though that may or may not be done implicitly). anyway, posting your views here might help with solving the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't have to set content: null, i think the .Controller is the problem as you hi-lighted.

Comment: p.s.: your setupController function looks a little weird compared to [the examples](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) and even if it's otherwise correct, i think you may need to change `args.id` to `args.file_id`

Comment: Ah! If I change it to an `ObjectController` it works (whether I have `content: null` or not).

As for the `args.id` I'm pretty sure that's right. It took me a lot of logging to realise that the setupController function is getting a rather different objects than the model function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Finn MacCool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2048165/finn-maccool) and [agmcleod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645132/agmcleod) I was trying to use the wrong type of controller. The correct lines should be:

```
App.FileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});
```

Not that I need to explicitly set a `FileController` in this small example. However, should I go on to expand the code I will no doubt need one and will need to use the correct one.